# Hashing large keys without collisions

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I am writing a checkers engine. I am aware of standard (zorbrist) hashing schemes, however because of the nature of my engine, they are unsuitable. Any collision of any sort will result in catastrophic errors.

To fix this, I would like to use the entire (unique) representation of the board state as the key. This should not really be a problem, since the state is determined by 6 32bit unsigned integers. This worked in python without any problems besides speed. In C++, I'm using std::unordered_map.

Every way I've tried to implement this has failed. I've tried an std::pair of boost::uint_type128 as the key. Again, there needs to be a guarantee that there won't be collisions.

Comment: Code the "hash" yourself?  Not entirely sure why a collision is death.  Hashes are supposed to collide occasionally.  Is a hash collision death because of runtime hit, dynamic memory hit, or something else?  Knowing this we maybe able to propose some other O(1) style search...

Comment: The hash table has move information as the entries. Collisions result in illegal moves and garbage positions polluting the search tree

Comment: If you want something fast, you'll have to make do with the types that can be supported natively. `std::size_t` is usually used, but that can't guarantee uniqueness for 6 x  32 bit values. You'll have to check for equality if you get a hit. Otherwise, you'll have to use 6 x 32 bits to store the unique value.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` doesn't care if the hashes are the same or not, as long as the keys themselves are different. It sounds like you're using a 256-bit key so I don't see the problem.

Comment: The problem is you are using `std::unordered_map`.  `std::unordered_map` is basically required to be implemented iike `std::vector<std::list<std::pair<const Key, value>>>`.  This is bad for performance even if you have zero coluisions and only gets worse from there.  Instead of trying to get zero collisions switch to a map type that uses a better implementation.  Chandler Carruth talks about this in his CPPCON 2014 talk: https://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs?t=2799

Comment: @MarkRansom Ok, so what type do I actually need to use as the key. That's all I need. I just want working code

Comment: It seems you want one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Comment: _"Any collision of any sort will result in catastrophic errors."_ -- this tells me that hashing is off the table and has no place in your question.

Comment: There seems to be important information missing from your question. You repeatedly mention "the key". The key to/for what? Also, what have you tried? What led you to believe it didn't work? (That might be the correct conclusion, but since you don't know how to fix it, we can't take your word for it.)

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Very nice talk - and the 2016 talk is too. Hard to stop watching. :-)